# Svelte environment variables: Uncaught ReferenceError: __myapp is not defined

Tags: svelte

I'm trying to add environment variables to a Svelte project. Tryied lots of solutions, including [this](https://medium.com/dev-cafe/how-to-setup-env-variables-to-your-svelte-js-app-c1579430f032) but all I get is the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: __myapp is not defined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article appears to be outdated, the `replace` function has to contain something like this. Check the readme for [plugin replace](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/replace#preventassignment).

add this to the `rollup.config.js`

```js
replace({
      values: {
        __myapp: JSON.stringify({
            isProd: production,
          ...config().parsed
        }),
      },
    }),
```

App.svelte file.

```html
<script>
  console.log(__myapp);
  const { isProd, API_URL } = __myapp;
</script>

<h4>{isProd} - {API_URL}</h4>
```